# C Endianness and byte array

Tags: c, virtual-machine, byte, endianness

I'm currently writing a virtual machine. Let's assume that there is an instruction that stores a 64-bit integer in a register and let's say that it looks like this: 0x00, [0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0xFF, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0xFF] where the part inside square brackets is the actual 64-bit integer in a big-endian format that will get placed in the register and those bytes are stored in a uint8_t array.

Is there any way to convert this array to a `uint64_t` without checking for the endianness of the host platform? I know in C++ there's a `std::endian::native`; however, I don't know about anything similar in C.

Comment: `x=((uint64_t)arr[0] << 56) + ((uint64_t)arr[1] << 48) + ... + arr[7];`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Would that convert the big endian to the host byte order (which could be big endian as well) or would it simply convert big to little endian

Comment: @EugeneSh. it actually assumes big endian

Comment: It will convert to whatever `uint64_t` means. Arithmetics are endian-agnostic.

Comment: @0___________ The source array is said to be BE.

Comment: @DanielNowak If the program is run on one machine and then the uint64_t will be sed in the binary form to machine with other endianess it will not work of course.  You need to provide more information.

Comment: @0___________ I *think* the op is writing an emulator of a BE machine, but the emulator itself should be portable to both BE and LE architectures. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you, that's exactly what I needed. Let's say it was a 32bit integer instead, would I start with ((uint32_t)arr[0] << 26 instead) ?

Comment: No << x where x has to dividable by 8. 26 is not

Comment: @DanielNowak You should count octets. You would start with 32-8=24

Comment: @EugeneSh. if it is run on the VM then there is nothing to convert as the VM will use its own endianess. I do not understand OPs problem.

Comment: @0___________ No, this is a code *of* the VM, compiled for the host. The array represents the VM memory. Now consider the op wants to, say, emulate the  addition of two VM memory locations using the native `+` operator. So they need to convert the memory location into the native integer type.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ah yes, too late for my brain to function properly and i thought 32 - 8 = 26.. Thanks again for the help

Comment: @0___________ Eugene has this exactly right.  Endianness only matters when you look at data from the outside, as a stream of bytes.  But "inside", a number is just a number.  If I say `int i` or `uint64_t u64`, it makes as little sense to ask whether these numbers are big-or little-endian as it does to ask what base they're in.  Eugene's code takes a big-endian external representation and portably converts it to the machine's internal implementation, whatever that happens to be.

Comment: @SteveSummit I understand what Eugene says and I do not argue :). I just do not understand OPs problemYou do not have to do anything from inside.

Comment: @0___________ I believe the OP wants to convert a byte array like `[0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0xFF, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0xFF]`.

Comment: When uP loads the data from memory (and memory is the byte array) to the register it does not have to convert anything

Comment: @0___________  If the OP is writing a virtual machine, in C, and the "machine language" which is the input to the virtual machine contains byte sequences like "0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0xFF, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0xFF", then the asked-for conversion is required and is properly performed as Eugene described.

Comment: @SteveSummit It is not a ASCII representation, the binary that's used simply contains those 8 bytes, before them there is a 0x00 which just means that those next 8 bytes are an integer which the register X is supposed to be set to